# Is is possible to install kdl_parser without having ROS in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, installation, ros

I have a URDF file of my robot, I am trying to define KDL tree inside C++ something like following:

```
KDL::Tree my_tree;
if (!kdl_parser::treeFromFile("robot.urdf", my_tree)){
    std::cout << "Failed to construct kdl tree"<< std::endl;
    return false;
}
```

The above code works with ROS. However, in another project, which is not a ROS project, I need to construct this KDL tree. This computer doesn't have ROS and sadly the OS is Windows.

**How to install [kdl_parser](http://wiki.ros.org/kdl_parser) without using ROS.**

*PS: I do not want to install ROS on Windows for this task.*

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to build the Library on windows, too:

http://www.orocos.org/kdl/installation-manual

Comment: Thank you. As per my information, kdl_parser is not a part of KDL. It is a separate tool designed for KDL by ROS community. Can you please confirm?

Comment: Okay, you can still try to build it: https://github.com/ros/kdl_parser It has probably little to no dependencies to ros. But it has dependencies to the kdl library [here](https://github.com/ros/kdl_parser/blob/melodic-devel/kdl_parser/include/kdl_parser/kdl_parser.hpp#L40), so you will have to build that anyways. ;-)